# How to program pcap with Objective-C and get HTTP request and response values in text format

Tags: objective-c, pcap, libpcap, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I am working with pcap in an OS X application to understand packet analysis.
I am working with a app https://github.com/jpiccari/MacAlyzer 
but I am getting only raw data but I want to differentiate every domain request into separate and clear way to read request and response value. Please guide me the way to how to develop an application with pcap.

I have tried some code but they translate data into hex format. How do I convert that data into meaningful request and response objects like Charles and Fiddler show?

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with "pocket"?

Comment: Sorry i should have used more clear tag like "packet-capture" "packet-sniffers", wrongly tag with pocket

Comment: What/who is Charles and Fiddler?

Comment: Charles and Fiddler are web proxy applications.

Comment: they are app use for debug http request and responce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacAlyzer wasn't developed for your needs. I know because I'm the author. As already stated, Charles and Fiddler are web proxies and work entirely different (and serve different purposes).

Diving a bit deeper into your question, communication between client and server happens IP-to-IP and not domain-to-domain. Domain information is not contained in the packets at the either the IP or TCP level. Instead computers request domain-to-IP lookup information which is then stored and communication is carried out using the client and server IP addresses.

MacAlyzer, and really libpcap, don't have sophisticated packet dissection (like say Wireshark) and cannot display packet information as verbosely as other programs. Before I lost interest in the project I was planning a library that would allow much richer packet dissection and analysis, but free time became very limited.

As for adding domain information to MacAlyzer, I'll explain at a high-level since it seems you know what you're doing. To include domain information instead of IP address in the Source and Destination columns you could edit function ip_host_string() in [ip.m](https://github.com/jpiccari/MacAlyzer/blob/master/MacAlyzer/ip.m). This function controls how the client and server addresses are displayed. Modifying it to lookup the [hostname from IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572697/how-to-get-domain-name-of-ipaddress-and-ipaddress-from-domain-name-in-objective) and returning the resulting string would cause the domains to be displayed instead of IP addresses.

If you come up with some nice updates, consider submitting a pull request.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing this answer! I gotta que for you, can you suggest me a more better way to develop the application like Charlse, I mean should i go with libpcap or is there any better lip to process that kind of communication....

Comment: libpcap is likely the wrong tool to use if you want to develop something like Charles. You'd need to write an HTTP proxy and inspect the requests before sending them off to the server. This can be easily accomplished in Chrome or Firefox extensions as there are APIs available to intercept this information. If you must write a standalone app I'll point you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505804/implementing-proxy-support-in-c-is-there-any-library-for-that)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the food for thoughts:

http://www.binarytides.com/packet-sniffer-code-c-linux/

Anyway, you will need to use C. Therefore, check the codes of the includes, for example:

http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs363/2014-spring/code/tcp.h

Here is the documentation of "pcap":

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.basetrf1/pcap_close.htm